# How to play and pause embedded wirewax videos?

Tags: iframe, video, youtube

How do you play/pause an embedded [wirewax](http://www.wirewax.com/home/create-own) video? The video is embedded using an iframe, using YouTube parameters after video i.e. `?loop=1&playlist=videoId` works, but the YouTube iFrame API doesn't.

```
<iframe src="//embed.wirewax.com/8020285/7bafa8/?enablejsapi=1&loop=1&playlist=802028" frameborder="0" id="video"></iframe>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="play">Play</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="pause">Pause</a></li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0cjjeev/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a quick copy paste from our iframe api documentation

Place the provided wirewax-iframe-api.js script in the head of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//edge-player.wirewax.com/ww4release/javascripts/wirewax-iframe-api.js"></script>
```

Give an ID to your WIREWAX  EMBED iframe . The default is wirewax-player, you can change this by setting the window.wirewax.playerId variable. An error will be thrown in the JavaScript Console if the iframe is not found.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.wirewax.playerId = "my-wirewax-player";
</script>

<iframe id="my-wirewax-player"></iframe>
```

**TRIGGERING WIREWAX EVENTS**

Events can be triggered by calling window.wirewax.triggerEvent(eventName, data).

Example:

```
window.wirewax.triggerEvent(window.wirewax.events.triggers.PLAY); // play the video

window.wirewax.triggerEvent(window.wirewax.events.triggers.SEEK, 20); // seek to 20 seconds
```

A list of event names can be found in window.wirewax.events.triggers

PLAY- Plays or resumes the video.

PAUSE- Pauses the video.

SEEK - Seeks the video to the value of data in seconds. data must be an int or float

IS_PLAYER_READY- Triggers the player ready event if the player is ready

Note that the player will only start accepting events once it is ready. You can check this by listening for the playerReady event.

**LISTENING FOR WIREWAX EVENTS**

Events that the player sends out can be listened to using

```
window.wirewax.addEventListener(eventName, callback)
```

Example:

```
window.wirewax.addEventListener(window.wirewax.events.listeners.PLAYER_READY, function(){
    console.log(“PLAYER IS READY”);
});

window.wirewax.addEventListener(window.wirewax.events.listeners.TAG_CLICK, function(data){
    console.log(data, “event data here”);
});
```

A list of event names can be found in window.wirewax.events.listeners

PLAYER_READY
Triggered when the player is ready

VIDEO_END
Triggered when the video has ended

TAG_CLICK
Triggered when a tag is clicked. Passes the tag object which has been clicked through to the callback

HAS_PAUSED
Triggered when the video is paused

HAS_PLAYED
Triggered when the video is played

Comment: can you send me a link to your API documentation?

Comment: It's currently not public, however i've copied in everything that pertains to sending and receiving messages to the player. If you have any questions just contact us via the contact page [link](http://www.wirewax.com/contact) and we'll get back to you asap

Comment: Thank you Danesh Harjani! I have one issue though, when I run the `window.wirewax.triggerEvent(window.wirewax.events.triggers.PAUSE);` method it pauses the video, but the sound keeps playing. Any ideas?

Comment: That's strange, i'm not seeing that on my end. What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome, let me update the fiddle and see if the issue persists or it's only my local.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle and it works on jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w0cjjeev/3/ so the issue must be on my local, thank you for the help again.

Comment: good to know it worked, if you make something cool with wirewax send us a link!

Comment: does anyone know how GO_TO_TAG works? (from https://jsfiddle.net/dnharjani/j1nLp98d/5/)